# Issue running Flask application with psycopg2 from PyCharmCE

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I am configuring a Flask application to use PostgreSQL and I have installed all necessary packages and dependencies as far as I am aware. Running my 'app.py' file from my system terminal or from a virtualenv seems to work.

The issue occurs when I try to run my 'app.py' file from within the same venv inside PyCharmCE.

```
  File "/Users/kilgow/Desktop/seasonwork_code/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1027, in create_engine
    return sqlalchemy.create_engine(sa_url, **engine_opts)
  File "<string>", line 2, in create_engine
  File "/Users/kilgow/Desktop/seasonwork_code/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 298, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kilgow/Desktop/seasonwork_code/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 560, in create_engine
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/Users/kilgow/Desktop/seasonwork_code/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 793, in dbapi
    import psycopg2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'

(<class 'ModuleNotFoundError'>, ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'psycopg2'"), <traceback object at 0x104b8fb00>)
```

Any ideas would be appreciated as I can't understand why the issue only occurs within PyCharm. I'm using macOS if there's any OS specific issues I'm unaware of.

Comment: try uninstall and re-install psycopg2, if it did not work, install psycopg2-binary

Comment: I'd tried this as a lot of places mentioned but no luck unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Working with modules it is usually a good practice to create a virtual environment. Afterward, install all the packages. Pycharm usually creates a virtual environment for you so before installing a package ensure your virtual environment is active.
For the case of `psycopg2` not found you resolve by
instead of `psycopg2` install `psycopg2-binary`

Comment: I should have clarified that I have tried using virtual environments both in and out of PyCharm. I can it working outside of PyCharm but not when running my app within the IDE which is strange.

Comment: Having global packages in your system may make your application behave differently when you now use a virtual environment. That's why it's necessary to create one to isolate your development packages from system-wide python packages